# geom_vline() ask for origin when combined with coord_polar()

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I combine `geom_vline` and `coord_polar` with a `Date` axis, it asks for origin. It works fine when `coord_polar` is not called.

```r
library(ggplot2)

data.frame(
  a = seq.Date(as.Date("2022-01-01"), as.Date("2022-01-31"), by= "1 day"),
  b = runif(31)
) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x=a, y=1, fill=b))+
  geom_tile(show.legend = FALSE)+
  geom_vline(xintercept=as.Date("2022-01-15"))+
  coord_polar()
#> Error in as.Date.numeric(value): 'origin' must be supplied
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

What is origin in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `coord_polar()` is not equipped for working with dates. Just transform the `xintercept` to numeric and it should just work (TM):

```r
library(ggplot2)

data.frame(
  a = seq.Date(as.Date("2022-01-01"), as.Date("2022-01-31"), by= "1 day"),
  b = runif(31)
) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x=a, y=1, fill=b))+
  geom_tile(show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(as.Date("2022-01-15")), size=2, color="red") +
  coord_polar()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Btw I really hope this is just a MVE, a circular graph with dates looks really confusing imo.

Comment: Thank you! And yes, this is just a MVE. The final plot is quite more complex.